# c# portable database connection strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection

below is the connection strings i have for my asp.net  project built in visual studio. But once the folder which contains the  prokject is tried to open on a different computer i get  database connection errors, is there a way i can make these  connection strings portable so that the project wont just run on my  computer only?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="nas_connect" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|app_code\nas.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="nasConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;app~_code\nas.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="nasConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;App_code\nas.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="nasConnectionString3" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;\App_code\nas.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="nasConnectionString4" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;\App_code\nas.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="insert into" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;\App_code\nas.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Your connection strings are pointing to your local database, that's why you can't connect to them from other pc.

Comment: @User555 what should it be  pointing to then?
the .mdf file is located in the app_data folder of the project.

Comment: The ip address of the machine e.g Data Source=192.168.2.122;

Comment: @User555 but i  want it to work on  any computer its opend on not just one  specific machine, the  website is stored on a  pen drive and i want it to be able  to run on  any machine its opened on.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly be ensure that you copy database files to another computer. I mean mdf and ldf files.(These files should be here `WebRoot/App_code/`.) And also be ensure that you install `SqlLocalDB.msi` to another computer.
Also if you want to have different configuration on different environments, I suggest to you use config file transformation. You can do it using for example `SlowCheetah` which one you can download using VS tools and extensions.

References:

1. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class for your connection string(s), this way you can access the connection string from anywhere in the application. Make sure your database files the .mdf and .ldf files are in your bin/Debug folder of your application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Loacal_DataBase
{
class Connection
{
   static string startupPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();      
   static readonly string connectString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=" + startupPath + "\\Local_DB.mdf";
   public SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString);

}
}
```